# Getting AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist when passing bucket name as bucket-name/10020/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using below code to get the objects present in the bucket.
I expect a empty response but code is throwing exception here.

```
final ListObjectsRequest listObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(s3Bucket)
                .withMaxKeys(1).withPrefix(prefix);
        final ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectRequest);
```

Parameters: 
s3_bucket => "my-bucket/incoming/"  and prefix => "PRE_"

Exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: BF85E6E0CF00717E)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1181) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:766) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:485) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:306) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3604) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3557) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.24.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:647) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.24.jar:?]
```

Comment: I think this is an expected behavior given that it couldn't find any object with provided key, or prefix in your case. You can catch the exception and return what you actually want.

Comment: But this method returns null if there is no value with s3_bucket and prefix. But I am getting exception here .